# Is dynamic SQL more performant than static SQL in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a work mate who claims that dynamic SQL performs faster than static SQL in many situations, so I constantly see DSQL all over the place. Aside from the obvious downsides like not being able to detect errors until running it and that it's harder to read, is this accurate or not? When I asked why he was using DSQL all the time, he said:

> Static is preferred when it is not going to prevent cache reuse and dynamic is preferred when static will prevent cache reuse and reuse is desirable.

I asked why static SQL would prevent cache reuse and he said:

> Apparently, when variables are passed to statement predicates it may prevent cache reuse of that execution plan, where DSQL will allow cache reuse in a stored procedure.

So, for example:

```
select * from mytable where myvar = @myvar
```

I'm not an expert in SQL Server execution plans, but this seems irrational to me. Why would the engine keep stats in a DSQL statement in a stored procedure, but not a static SQL statement?

Comment: You'd need to show the DSQL equivalent of `select * from mytable where myvar = @myvar` because one approach is to put the value there as part of the string, therefore removing the parameter. So yes, you avoid the parameter sniffing at the expense of having 1 query plan for every possible value of `@myvar`.

Comment: Performance wise, try it out, obtain the execution plan for the static version and compare it to the dynamic version.

Comment: Coding wise it sounds like a nightmare. Parameter sniffing (which is what your colleague is referring to is only sometimes, I would go as far to say rarely, an issue - google it).

Comment: Tell your work mate to read documentation about what `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` does. Also, both of you should read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) and [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic SQL has the advantage that a query is recompiled every time it is run.  This has the advantage that the execution plan can take advantage of the most recent statistics on the table and the values of any parameters.

In addition to being more readable, static SQL has the advantage that it does not need to be recompiled -- saving a step in running the query (well, actually two if you count parsing-->compiling-->executing).  This may or may not be a good thing.

You can force static plans to recompile using the `with (recompile)` option.

Sometimes, you need to use dynamic SQL.  As a general rule, though, I would use compiler hints and other efforts to manage performance *before depending on dynamic SQL*.

Comment: More readable and checked for syntax errors and missing objects at the time of writing as opposed to runtime.

Comment: "Dynamic SQL has the advantage that a query is recompiled every time it is run." This statement is simply not true. Compilation and recompilation doesn't depend on the query text being generated dynamically or statically.

Answer (score 0):

From SQL server perspective, I don't think you should be using dynamic SQL much.
Problems can include :

1. In memory table will be passed read only
2. With every value concatenated, query will do recompilation.

Execution plan will anyway use table statistics and other db information, but do you need to recompile execution plan. You can mend your queries to use LOOP JOIN, HASH JOIN or MERGE JOIN yourself if you feel you know better than SQL Server engine. Otherwise, just write procedures the way they are intended to be written, and pass parameters.

In my opinion, do not use dynamic queries...Instead use procedures in which every change-able value is passed as parameter and has no hard-coding. Create proper (and fewer) indexes and triggers to deal with data. You will also be hence be able to easily use `in memory table variables` and `memory tables` feature directly otherwise `in memory table variables` are passed to dynamic query as readonly.

Comment: Known facts constitute my opinion in SQL....If you try to use dynamic queries with in memory table variables, you will know. Those are passed as read only, and changes are then transferred to main table. Also, recompilation step is there.